# Does Power BI Data Flows over Public Internet

Tags: security, azure, architecture, powerbi

I am new to Power BI and working on its pilot implementation in my organisation. However, there are a few architectural questions that have slowed my progress.

**Scenario**
1. My data source is an on-premise tabular model (SSAS) 
2. Gateway is installed and configured properly
3. I have created a few reports using Power BI Desktop. Data source for these is an on-premise tabular model, I mentioned above in 1.
4. I have got 10 Power BI Pro License

**Questions**
1. When a user wants to access a report hosted on the Power BI cloud does the report gets downloaded into my organisation's network and then runs? If not does it stays in the Power BI cloud and runs from the cloud itself?

2. If the report runs on the Power BI cloud, does my organisation data moves over Public internet?
3. If the data runs over Public Internet, then does it mean that I have to increase my organisation's public internet handling capacity? How secure is the Azure channel in handling data over public internet?

I will appreciate if anyone in the group can answer them.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> When a user wants to access a report hosted on the Power BI cloud does the report gets downloaded into my organisation's network and then runs?

Yes and no. Power BI uses javascript to render visualisations. Those visualisations are rendered in your internet browser. The aggregation of data is done in the Power BI service and that is turned into a visualisation on the local computer.

> If the report runs on the Power BI cloud, does my organisation data moves over Public internet?

Yes it does. Both the data from the gateway up to Azure and the Power BI web page that is rendered and shown to a user in the browser.

> If the data runs over Public Internet, then does it mean that I have to increase my organisation's public internet handling capacity?

That's hard to know. You should do some testing to see if you need to. There will be a component of upload and download to consider if you are using the gateway.

> How secure is the Azure channel in handling data over public internet?

Azure is very secure. Here is a link to the MS trust center which describes the security and compliance to standards: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/TrustCenter/CloudServices/Power-BI